# Do outpost siege abilities stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I ran four [Outpost Siege](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Outpost%20Siege)s had two of them on the field, would the effects stack?

Moreover would the effect stack if I chose Khans/ Dragons twice?

Basically if I had two Outpost Sieges would it allow me to exile two cards and play them each upkeep/ deal two damage as opposed to one if a creature leaves the battlefield?

Comment: You can attack with two creatures with a same name at the same time, cast two instants with the same name at the same time. I'm curious what made you doubt that enchantments would work the same way.

Comment: @tsuma534 While your conclusion is correct, your analogies are quite irrelevant to the question and explain nothing, because those cases are governed by entirely different sections of the rules. Additionally, you can **not** cast 2 instants at the same time. You always cast spells and activate abilities one at a time.

Comment: @Hackworth Technically, yes - instants aren't cast the same time. But they can exist on the stack at the same time. I think a comment is a place that allow simplifications, as I only needed to highlight why I'm curious.

Comment: @tsuma534 While I understand your curiosity, I don't think you'll often get interesting answers - things like this are usually just about having incomplete mental models of the way the game works, with some intuition mixed in.

Comment: @Jefromi Well, it was worth trying - sometimes I do get an answer. I'm always eager to know why people don't get one rule or another. This helps me with addressing future rule concerns and with designing my own rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each Outpost Siege will trigger at the beginning of each upkeep. Example:

- You play Outpost Siege, naming Khans.
- You play Outpost Siege, naming Dragons.
- At the beginning of your upkeep, both Outpost Sieges trigger.
- You stack the triggers in whatever order you choose.
- You resolve the triggers in the opposite order.

  - As each trigger resolves, follow the instructions written on the card.

If you control three Outpost Sieges, then all three will trigger. If you control ten, then all ten will trigger. There's no rule that says, "Only one enchantment with the same name can trigger at the same time."

Answer (score 3):

603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities he or she controls on the stack in any order he or she chooses. (See rule 101.4.) Then the game once again checks for and resolves state-based actions until none are performed, then abilities that triggered during this process go on the stack. This process repeats until no new state-based actions are performed and no abilities trigger. Then the appropriate player gets priority.

I think this rule answers your question.
Basically you get to choose the order in which they stack.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Each Outpost Siege will trigger and resolve separately.